# I need a formula to show me how munch more of a Quantity I need to Invest to make my Cost Avg equal/as close to the dollar of Current Price

Tags: google-sheets, formula, average, finance

[image]

Note: (The **Cost Avg** is dividing the **Investment** by **Quantity**)

I understand what the math equation would look like but not how to make it into an excel formula.

I am trying to solve for X. Can you help me turn the below into a google sheet formula?

(X***Current Price**)+**Investment**/(X+**Quantity**)=**Current Price** or

(x*F4+G4)/(x+D4)=F4

Comment: Provide sample inputs and example output for that input.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some luck in math community, but I am afraid, that the answer you are looking for is always *infinity* except in two rare scenarios - if you have zero quantity or current price is equal to your current average cost.

Lets take a look at all those 3 scenarios starting from the end.

**Scenario 1: if current cost is already equal to your cost average.**

For example you have 5 units with average cost of 2 and current price is 2. You can buy 0 or *any* amount of units and the price won't change.

**Scenario 2: you don't have any units.**

Lets say current price is 2 and you don't have any units. To get your average price to current price you need to buy any amount - would it be 0.00001, 20, 10000 or whatever.

**Scenario 3: you have some units at average price and current price is not equal to it.**

Let's say you have 5 units with average cost of 2 and current price is 3. More units you buy at current price, closer your current average cost gets to  current price, so the answer is infinity, as much as you can, as much as possible and so on:

[image]

**Extra scenario: I misunderstood you completely**

Update to comment with current price lower than current average cost:

[image]

Solution to your equation `(x*5+100)/(x+10)=5`:

[image]

So

```
5x+100=5x+10
100=10
```

no solution.

Comment: The screenshot you provided has a price higher than the average cost. You wouldn't care for an answer in that scenario.  The point of this would be to lower your average cost down because the current  price is lower than your avg cost. Lets work with smaller numbers to show you how my math problem works.   Token-Amp  Qty-10 Cost avg=10 Current price:5 Investment:100        If you solve for X:   (x*F4+G4)/(x+D4)=F4

(x*5+100)/(x+10)=5

Comment: It doesn't matter. I have updated post with example with current price lower than your average cost. More you buy, closer your average costs goes to current, but never equal. Also equation (x*5+100)/(x+10)=5 is unsolvable (updated too).

Comment: Right it doesn't have to be equal exactly, close to the dollar amount as my title suggests. In the example I gave you, 41 would be the amount to get you $5.98 cents.  I could use a higher number to get closer, but I'm happy getting as close within a dollar. I know excel and sheets have "round up" options to say you're willing to get a round up answer.

Comment: Then the answer is the more you buy the closer it gets.

Comment: Right, but I wanted to have a cell tell me the amount instead of me having to plug in different numbers.  Once you get to the dollar amount the numbers get ridiculously large just to shave a few cents.  Like hundreds more. I only want the cell to show me the number that gets me within a buck.

Comment: If you want price to be current price +1 dollar so your equation should be (x*F4+G4)/(x+D4)=F4 +1 and not (x*F4+G4)/(x+D4)=F4. For example (x*5+100)/(x+10)=6 is solvable and x=40. So formula for x would be =G4-F4*D4-D4, in your data set it will only work for bitcoin (and will give result of x =1836.943947 to get average cost to current cost +1), as your cost average must be higher than current price+1. More universal formula would be =(G4-F4*D4)/z-D4 where z is tolerance in dollars (difference between current price and desired result)

Comment: A few things here.
a)Price to be current + 1 dollar, I think you're not understanding what I mean. I want it to be within a dollar range, meaning the formula needs to the closest number that gets me within a dollar range. Example:41 coins got me 5.98

b)when you say average cost must be higher - Correct, the only point of doing this is when that is the case. I don't want to invest more in the coin when it currently cost higher than my avg cost.
c)when you say a universal formula would be "=(G4-F4*D4)/z-D4"...excel does not let you put expressions that have variables. There can be no "z"